# llvm segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm

I'm developing an llvm front-end. My problem is that when I use the 'store' instruction to store a value in a member of a complex type I get segmentation fault. For example, assume I've defined a type like %mytype = type {i32, ...} in a module, then I use the following commands to store 3 in the first field of an object of this type. What's wrong with this code that causes seg fault?

```
define void f() {
...
%alloc = alloca %mytype*
%myinstance = load %mytype** %alloc
%firstfield = getelementptr %mytype* %myinstance, i32 0, i32 0
store i32 3, i32* %firstfield
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have allocated a *pointer* without allocating what it's pointing to, so it's no wonder you're getting a segmentation fault when you try to dereference that pointer.

What you need to do is

```
%alloc = alloca %mytype
%firstfield = getelementptr %mytype* %alloc, i32 0, i32 0
store i32 3, i32* %firstfield
```

If for some reason you still need to alloca a pointer - in other words, you want a value of `%mytype**` pointing to a memory location where there's a pointer to the allocated memory - then you can also add to the above:

```
%ptrptr = alloca %mytype*
store %mytype* %alloc, %mytype** %ptrptr
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is that I should allocate a pointer, i.e. I can't replace 'alloca %mytype*' with 'alloca %mytype'

Comment: @user1723583 in that case you need two distinct `alloca` instructions - one to allocate the memory of the object, and the other to allocate a memory for a pointer. I updated my answer accordingly.